# How to make Data lombok return deep copys of getter method

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Spotbugs is giving the following Error warnings:

[ERROR] Medium: MetaData.getCreatedAt() may expose internal representation by returning MetaData.createdAt [...MetaData] At MetaData.java:[line 21] EI_EXPOSE_REP

To solve this i think i have to return a deep copy of the "createdAt".

Is there a solution to solve this directly with @Data?

Comment: You might want to provide some more details, e.g. the code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is none. The reason is that creating a defensive copy is different for each class, and the best way to do so depends on your use case. Lombok cannot know what you want or need.

For example, consider a mutable class with a modifiable list as a field, i.e. the list contents may change concurrently with the `getList()` call. In some cases, it could be reasonable to return a `Collections.unmodifiableList()` that will reflect the changes to the list that may concurrently occur. In other cases it may be better to return a list that never changes, e.g. creating a true copy of the list by `List.copyOf()`.
Furthermore, if the objects in the list are also mutable, you may want to clone/copy those, too.

So if you want to return a defensive copy, you have to implement the getter manually.